# Avoiding radio input getting focus when an input element in its label is selected in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, firefox3.6

I have read this question and I am having the same problem:
[Put text input inside label for radio button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942236/put-text-input-inside-label-for-radio-button)

Feel free to take a look using Firefox (Chrome and IE8 do not have this problem.):
http://pastehtml.com/view/1dbqqb3.html

I now understand some javascript has to be used to fix this behavior in Firefox.

But I have no idea how to write this piece of codes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As noted in the related question... nesting an input element inside the label for another input control isn't supported in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some html:

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" />
<input id="text1" onfocus="selectRadioBtn('radio1')" />
```

The JavaScript:

```
function selectRadioBtn(id)
{
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```